# How can I free up space when receiveing QuotaExceededError?

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

I am using IndexedDB to cache data for a web app, and want to free up space by deleting older data when the transaction aborts due to QuotaExceededError events.

I tried queuing "delete" transactions upon receiving the abort event, but they fail too, triggering QuotaExceededError themselves.

I cannot figure out what to do.

This was on up-to-date Firefox.